# Calculating Fair Stock Price

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value, brownian-motion

I've got the following exercise for uni:

[image]

I have solved (a) but I'm really struggling with (b). I know that I'm looking for $V(0)$, where $V(t) = \tilde{E}[e^{-r(T-t)}1_{S(T)>K}|F(t)]$, but I'm not sure how to do this. In my book, the solution to the Black-Scholes-Merton formula is given, but this uses another payoff function $V$, so I don't think this is the key. Also, $\tilde{E}$, expectation under risk-neutral measure isn't really defined properly in my book, so I can't calculate it directly either. I'm kind of at a dead end here, could anyone help me with this? Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: The risk neutral measure is defined as the probability measure such that the discounted stock price is a martingale. So by the choosing the $c(t)$ obtained in part a) and setting $S(t) = e^{W(t) + c(t)}$, the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ is a risk neutral measure.

Comment: Note that the call option price is given by $E[e^{-r(T-t)}(S(T) - K)1_{S(T)>K}|F(t)] = E[e^{-r(T-t)}S(T)1_{S(T)>K}|F(t)] - KE[e^{-r(T-t)}1_{S(T)>K}|F(t)]$. So you compare the second part of the Black-Scholes formula you can find the answer directly. Alternatively, by noticing the Brownian motion $W(t)$ has a normal distribution, you can also directly derive the expectation in terms of the normal CDF.